# How can I make Android Studio IDE Fullscreen?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've googled this and all I found is how to make an app full screen. But I want the IDE to be fullscreen. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `View` menu, choose `Appearance`, then `Enter Full Screen`.

Comment: 2022 update: `View` → `Appearance` → `Enter Full Screen`